# bulk find and replace in google docs using sheet and app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Thank you in advance.

I am trying to multiple finds and replace google docs with a reference google sheet

```
Find            |  Replace  
----------------------------
bill number one | Bill No. 1
Bill number one | Bill No. 1
Bill number 1   | Bill No. 1
Bill Number One | Bill No. 1
Bill Number 1   | Bill No. 1
```

```
function replMyText(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1-WblrS95VqsM5eRFkWGIHrOm_wGIPL3QnPyxN_j5cOo');
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('find and replace');
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var docrange=doc.getBody()
  var rgtxt=doc.getBody();//text to replace
  var rgrep=sh.getRange('A2:B103');//replacement table
  var txtA=rgtxt.getText();
  var repA=rgrep.getValues();
  
  for(var i=0;i<txtA.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<repA.length;j++){
      if(txtA[i][0]==repA[j][0]){
        txtA[i][0]=repA[j][1];
      }
    }
  }
  rgtxt.setText(txtA);
}
```

I did not get the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to replace the text in Google Document using the values retrieved from Google Spreadsheet.
- The columns "A" and "B" in Google Spreadsheet are the search text and the replace text, respectively.

In this case, I thought that `replaceText()` might be able to be used. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function replMyText() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1-WblrS95VqsM5eRFkWGIHrOm_wGIPL3QnPyxN_j5cOo');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('find and replace');
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var rgtxt = doc.getBody();
  var rgrep = sh.getRange('A2:B103');
  var repA = rgrep.getValues().filter(r => r.every(c => c.toString()));
  repA.forEach(e => rgtxt.replaceText(...e));
}
```

#### Reference:

- [replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement)

Comment: can tell me how can add exact match ex. last names like "Williams." at the end of a sentence to "WilliaMs." I want ms to replace MS.

Comment: @Sachin Pathare Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about what you want to do. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. So can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand your new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66800898/7419737 hope you understand.
ありがとうございました

Comment: @Sachin Pathare Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that your new question had already been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to do this without a script, you can do it right in Google Sheets with the powerful `ARRAYFORMULA()` function

[image]

Comment: They don't want to do it without a script. That is specified explicitly in the question. The question was how to do it with a script.

Comment: Just figured wouldn’t do any harm to add this alternative to this thread with the disclaimer