# bulk find and replace with a condition case match and exact match google app script,doc,sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs, google-docs-api

Thank you in advance.

I have a sheet with data as follows.

| Find | Replace | condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Page number ten | Page No. 10 | match case |
| Page number 10 | Page No. 10 | match case |
| ms | Ms | exact match |

I want to find and replace text in docs with the condition.
The below code works fine for me but whenever ex. Willia**ms** it replace with Willia**Ms**.

```
function replMyText() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1-WblrS95VqsM5eRFkWGIHrOm_wGIPL3QnPyxN_j5cOo');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('find and replace');
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var rgtxt = doc.getBody();
  var rgrep = sh.getRange('A2:B103');
  var repA = rgrep.getValues().filter(r => r.every(c => c.toString()));
  repA.forEach(e => rgtxt.replaceText(...e));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need capture group of regex for properly capturing all cases, not just words between spaces. `(e.g. ms. “ms” ms, ms! ms?  ms! ‘ms’)`

But since `replaceText` doesnt support capture group while `replace` does, we need to derive it using `replace` inside `replaceText`.

#### EDIT:

#### Code:

```
function replMyText() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1-WblrS95VqsM5eRFkWGIHrOm_wGIPL3QnPyxN_j5cOo');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('find and replace');
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var rgtxt = doc.getBody();
  var rgrep = sh.getRange('A2:C103');
  var repA = rgrep.getValues().filter(r => r.every(c => c.toString()));

  // Search per paragraph so it won't produce exponential copies per paragraph
  var paragraphs = rgtxt.getParagraphs();
  for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
    repA.forEach(function(e){
      if(e[2] == "match case") {
        DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().replaceText(e[0], e[1]);
      }
      else if (e[2] == "exact match") {
        // Only replace the string in between non [a-zA-Z0-9_]
        // Capture string including 2 \W characters around it, then pad them around the replaced string
        var replace = "(\\W)" + e[0] + "(\\W)";
        var re = new RegExp(replace, "g");
        var text = paragraphs[i].getText();
        paragraphs[i].replaceText(".*", text.replace(re, "$1" + e[1] + "$2"));

        // Replace the ones starting in a paragraph if present
        replace = "^" + e[0] + "(\\W)";
        re = new RegExp(replace, "g");
        text = paragraphs[i].getText();
        paragraphs[i].replaceText(".*", text.replace(re, e[1] + "$1"));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

#### Latest update tests:

[image: sample3]

#### Latest update output:

[image: output2]

#### References:

- [variable in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)
- [capture group in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968419/replacetext-regex-not-followed-by/54325652)

Comment: Checking @SachinPathare

Comment: Kindly check the updated code now @SachinPathare. Recently modified something from my previous edit. see edit history above if needed.

Comment: thank you for modifying the code. now the exact match not working.

Comment: I have recently modified the script. You might have tested the older one. can you test again? @SachinPathare

Comment: tested older one script and recent but still, not working exact match, match case run properly @NaziA

Comment: I retested my script and it still works (edited my answer to show the updated tests). Maybe providing a sample sheet/doc would be best to test this on your provided sample data. @SachinPathare

Comment: Thank you so much for your help really appreciate.